# Square root of complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How do I find the square root of complex number $7-(6\sqrt2)i$?

I hope there's someone who can show me the method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "THE squareroot of a complex number". It is better to write "Solve the equation $x^2=7-(6\sqrt{2})i$ for $x$ and you get two answers, neither of them being positive or negative since they also will be...complex

Comment: We'll need to write this in the form $re^{i\theta}$ and use de Moivre.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Good catch

Comment: try $a + b i \sqrt 2,$ squre it and see if you get $a,b$ integers or at least rational. $3 - i \sqrt 2$ works, did it in my head

Comment: @WillJagy I worked it out, got the answers and indeed the imaginary component has a square root. What is going on in your head:) ?

Comment: @imranfat  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPzY30v9mtg

Comment: @WillJagy Hey awesome...

Comment: See more general situation in [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908074/quadratic-formula-in-complex-variables/1908263#1908263).

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{7-6\sqrt{2}i}=\sqrt{7+2-2-6\sqrt{2}i}=\sqrt{9-6\sqrt{2}i-2}=\sqrt{3^2-2*3\sqrt{2}i+(\sqrt2i)^2}=\sqrt{(3-\sqrt{2}i)^2}$$

Comment: Nice way, but honestly, you got to see that one somehow...There are also two solutions from your square root.